# I am trying to build a gui using pyqt5 to predict image class but I get no output

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, prediction

here is the code, I have deleted the code in the middle just to simplify it and help me to solve the issue.
I can display an image but I can't make a prediction it just close the GUI when I press the classification button. so, how I can solve this issue?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
from PIL import Image
import cv2, imutils
from keras.models import load_model

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        ..........
       self.input.clicked.connect(self.clicker)
       self.classification.clicked.connect(self.getClassify)
def clicker(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Open File",
                                            r"C:\\Users\\Alaa alsheikheh\\PycharmProjects\\MyProject\\pre_process\\dataset\\test_img\\",
                                            "All Files (*);;PNG Files (*.png);;Jpg Files (*.jpg)")
        # Open The Image

        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(fname[0])
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

def getClassify(self,fname):

        width = 299
        height = 299
        img_array=cv2.imread(str(fname))
        img=Image.resize(img_array,(width,height))
        img = numpy.asarray(img, dtype=numpy.float32)
        img = tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
       # image =  image /255
        model = load_model('../MyProject/pre_process/TrainModel.h5')
        pred = model.predict(img)
        pred = (numpy.argmax(pred[0]))
        if pred == 0:
                self.result.setText('No_DR')
        if pred == 1:
                self.result.setText('Mild')
        if pred == 2:
                self.result.setText('Moderate')
        if pred == 3:
                self.result.setText('Severe')
        if pred == 4:
                self.result.setText('Proliferate_DR')




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Might mean the C++ code is crashing or something, try add `return` at various points in the function to see if any line is causing the crash.

Comment: it is in python. also, i tried to add return before  self.classification.setText but still I don't get the output

Comment: If pressing the button crashes the whole application so the window disappears without an error, it can be the C++ code in one of the libraries hitting an error. I was just suggesting to add the return statements to check what line is causing that crash, which you can then try and debug once you find it.

Comment: I was trying that right now but still, the same thing happen.

Comment: Try go all the way up to the start of `getClassify` if you haven't already. If you return instantly before doing anything, then it shouldn't close down the window.

Comment: still it does not work

Comment: Try to run your program in a terminal or prompt and see if you get any output. Also add a main `try/except` block in `getClassify` and print the exception.

Comment: i tried to put try: (code) except: return self.result.setText("error") and now it print error